# Sending data between Navigation Drawer Fragments

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-viewmodel

Let me first describe my app on the surface level.

1. App has navigation drawer which was generated by Android with 2 default views (new navigation controller).

   a.  HomeView

   b.  HistoryView
2. I have created a viewmodels for data exchange

   a.  DataViewModel

Problems:

1. When I switch to HistoryView and try to change the message it never gets observed into the HomeView.
2. When I switch back to HomeView then I see the last changed value in console.

@james04 mentioned to add the come code for the reference - here it is -

MainActivity -

```
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_history)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

HomeFragment -

```
        // @onCreateView 

        dataViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(DataViewModel.class);

        // @onViewCreated

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
            dataViewModel.getMessage().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(String s) {
                    Log.d("MESSAGES","Labels - > " + s); 
                }
            });
        }
```

HistoryFragment -

```
    // @onCreateView 

    dataViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(getActivity()).get(DataViewModel.class);


    // @onViewCreated 

    setMessages.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
    RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int id) {
                switch (id){
                    case R.id.apple: 
                        dataViewModel.setMessage("Apple");
                        break;
                    case R.id.banana: 
                        dataViewModel.setMessage("Banana");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: i think we should see some code...

Comment: Okay I will add in sometime.

Comment: @james04 I have updated the question with code. Sorry I got busy a little bit.

Comment: This is the documentation for creating shared viewmodels https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try to not to instantiate the viewModel in every fragment, but instead instantiate it in the MainActivity and get the reference from each fragment through the activity. Example

MainActivity

```
public DataViewModel dataViewModel;

onCreate () {
   ......
   dataViewModel = new ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DataViewModel.class)
}
```

And on each fragment get the viewModel as below

```
dataViewModel.getMessage().observe(this, new Observer()...)
```

And setting the value to message with the same way

```
   getActivity().dataViewModel.setMessage("Apple");
```

*Also move the codes from the fragments from onActivityCreated to onViewCreated*

Comment: thanks for the reply - getActivity().dataViewModel.setMessage("Apple"); is giving me error. getActivity().[.................].setMessage("Apple"); dataviewmodel isn't referenceing I have also tried this MainActivity.getInstance().dataViewmodel.setMessage but same error.

Comment: I dont understand the error...its a public variable so if u call getActvity().dataViewModel.anything_else_here its visible from the fragments. Can you gimme the error exaclty and the line that happens?

Comment: @jameso4 so I fixed it by doing this.  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).dataViewModel.setMessage() . But the problem still persists, I can't observe values until I change the Fragment to home from History. And it only show the last value set in History.

Comment: Ohh yeah...sorry u needed to cast it!! Pff...i dont know. There is an problem in the way u set it up. Can u share the code in a repository or its a commercial product?

Comment: https://filebin.net/gzu3iyspl46edtn6/DemoNavDrawer.zip?t=14f1fyut

Comment: Well i run the project and cannot understand ur problem? When i go to SettingFragment and change the Language i can see the Log in the SettingsViewModel setLanguage funcation and when i go back to HomeFragm the observer returns the last value.... :/

Comment: okay if that's normal then it is fine because I thought when you change values in setting fragment it should change  get observed in real time in the homefragment, not when you switch to homeFragment. Can you please explain me what exactly happening.?

Comment: The "Observer" is a guy that gets fired every time the value he observe changes, BUT u have registered him in a particular lifecycle (getViewLifecycleOwner()), That means that when the HomeFragment is not visible the Observer guy is not registered so he does not observes anything because he doesn't exists. Thats because the HomeFragment by that time is not visible.
When the HomeFtagment comes back to visible then the Observer starts again and sees the changed value from SettingsFragment